# PHP: update fields ONLY if replacement is present. If not, remain untouched

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, php-7

I think it is a classical one, but in one of my Laravel controllers, I need to update the value of some fields ONLY if the corresponding replacement values are present in the incoming request. If they are not present, the must stay untouched. My "smartest" try so far:

```
$user->name = $request->name ?: $user->name;
$user->email = $request->email ?: $user->email;
...
```

Is there a smarter way of doing this using latest PHP or Laravel enhancements?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If form key names and DB table column names are same, collect only those who have values and loop over them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but they are not all the same so I discarded that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`get()`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_get) method on the request and pass the current value as the default value.

```
$user->name = $request->get('name', $user->name);
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reply. Looking at the docs, it seems like the preferred method for accessing input is `input` instead of `get`. I'll use the first to avoid mid term deprecation issues.

Comment: And @Jerodev, given the situation, is there a better approach in update methods than doing this in terms of app structure?

Comment: The only difference is that `get` will check all available parameter bags and `input` will check the parameter bag that is related to the request method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a ternary operator and just check if the $request->name isen't null or empty.

Like so:

`$user->name = (($request->name === NULL) ? $user->name : $request->name);`

Answer (score 0):

Typically in a Laravel controller `update` method, you are passing the entire model attribute array through in the `$request`.  Your worry is that an empty/null value present in this array would automatically update the database column to null.

Not to worry, the [`sometimes` validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) is your friend.

```php
public function update(Request $request, Model $model) 
{
    $validated = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'sometimes|string',
        'email' => 'sometimes|email',
        // ...
    ]);

    $model->update($validated);
}
```